# Sequelize - Table Pluralization Error, No Instance within Table

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I have run into a weird error where I receive a message for a pluralization version of my database table and it is being grouped into my sequel query. I scanned my models and routes and couldn't find any instance of a pluralization of my table name, and when I check the database tables the structures do not mention any pluralization. When I log the query, it looks like the pluralization error comes in at this section of the query

FROM `images` AS `images` LEFT OUTER JOIN `descriptions` AS `description` ON

Here is the full error message:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'assistant.descriptions' doesn't exist
```

Here is my `Images` model:

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){

```
var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: DataTypes.STRING,
    color: DataTypes.STRING,
    imageUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    imageSource: DataTypes.STRING,
    description_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Images.belongsTo(db.Description, {foreignKey: 'description_id'});
        }
    }
});
    return Images;
}
```

Here is my `Description` model:
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

```
var Description = sequelize.define('description', {
    description_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    color: DataTypes.STRING,
    body: DataTypes.STRING
});
    return Description;
}
```

Here is how I associate the models in `dbIndex`:

```
var Sequelize      = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize("assistant", "admin", "pwd", {
    host: "host",
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
var db = {};

db.Description = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/descriptionModel");

db.Images = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/imagesModel");

db.Images.associate(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Here is my query:

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res, image){

    console.log(req.params.color);
    console.log(req.params.pattern);

    db.Images.findAll({ 
        where: {
            pattern: req.params.pattern,
            color: req.params.color
        },
        include: [db.Description],
        attributes: ['id', 'pattern', 'color', 'imageUrl', 'imageSource', 'description_id']
    }).then(function(image){
        //console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
        res.render('pages/suit-result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
            })
        });
});
```

Here is the query before the error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `images`.`id`, `images`.`pattern`, `images`.`color`, `images`.`imageUrl`, `images`.`imageSource`, `images`.`description_id`, `description`.`description_id` AS `description.description_id`, `description`.`color` AS `description.color`, `description`.`body` AS `description.body`, `description`.`createdAt` AS `description.createdAt`, `description`.`updatedAt` AS `description.updatedAt` FROM `images` AS `images` LEFT OUTER JOIN `descriptions` AS `description` ON `images`.`description_id` = `description`.`description_id` WHERE `images`.`pattern` = 'solid' AND `images`.`color` = 'navy-blue';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seqeulize will pluralize your table names by default.  To turn it off, include the option `freezeTableName: true` to all your model definition options that you don't want pluralized.  For example, with the Description model:

```
var Description = sequelize.define('description', {
  description_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  color: DataTypes.STRING,
  body: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});
```